# Change PDF title in browser window

Tags: pdf, browser, title

I have a pdf file that I am putting on a website for a client. It is located here...
http://www.optiphysicaltherapy.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/OPTI_NewPatientForms.pdf

The title should be OPTI New Patient Forms but if you look at the tab in the browser and the name at the top of the browser window it says "Coury And..."

Where can I go to change this?

The website is using Wordpress 3.8.1 and I am not sure if it is in Wordpress or in the actual pdf file.

Thank you,

Matt

Comment: Its shows the `URL` for me...

Comment: It shows the URL in the address bar but at the very top and in the tab in Firefox it shows the Coury and.. text. Doesn't show up in IE or Chrome.

Comment: And what is preventing you from changing it?

Comment: Good question. I don't know where to change it. It is not an HTML based page, it's a pdf. I have never seen a meta title in a pdf and am asking where I can go to change it.

Comment: Well first take a look at this http://wordpress.org/support/topic/changing-title-on-browser-tab and its pretty straight forward. Since Wordpress is in PHP, that's might be why it looks a bit challenging.

Comment: I honestly don't think that is it. I don't have that name anywhere related to the Wordpress site. I think it is part of the actual pdf. Is there a meta-title setting in pdfs?

Comment: The text displayed in the browser tab has _nothing_ to do with the PDF.

Comment: See, below. If the PDF has a meta-title it will show in Firefox as if it were the meta-title for a webpage. This is only when displaying just the pdf in the browser.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ok, So I found out how to change the meta-data in a .pdf form here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7c63.w.html (dead link; archived version [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150929053233/http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7c63.w.html))

Sure enough the Title in the Meta Data within the .pdf was "Coury And..."

Once I changed this the Tab and the Title in Firefox web browser changed to have the title that I wanted.

This shows us that the meta-data in the .pdf does show in Firefox as if it were the meta-title of the webpage when displaying a .pdf within the browser.

Comment: Appears that Chrome just shows file path, but FireFox uses the Title meta-data tag.

Comment: That link is now dead. Adobe ceased support of the version in that link.

Comment: According to [this link](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/pdf-properties-metadata.html) it's `File > Properties`.

Comment: Unix-users can use `exiftool -Title="This is the Title" drawing.pdf` as in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/39906/533341).

Comment: Archived version of link at https://web.archive.org/web/20150929053233/http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7c63.w.html

Answer (score 28):

Open the PDF with [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and search (CTRL+F) for /Title
Change title between brackets (and leave the brackets)
For instance:
Change "/Title (OLD TITLE)" into "/Title (This is my new title)"

Save the PDF and Voila

Comment: I guess this should be the accepted solution. OS agnostic and works fine. You could use any text editor.

Comment: Notepad or other code editors didn't work...
And Here is a video about it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJw77is-f50

Comment: This didn't work for me. I opened my problematic PDF in Notepad++, searched for the string "title" via CTRL+F, and got no matches. Boo! (Judging by one of the few non-gibberish parts of the file as viewed in Notepad++, it looks like this particular PDF may have been created with Google's PDFium. Not sure if that has anything to do with it.) I ended up using Adobe Acrobat Pro to edit the file and solve the problem, as per MattM's accepted answer.

Comment: This solution is simple and worked for me.

Answer (score 26):

If you have access to the Word document in which the PDF is based, you can define the title when you save the file.

[image]

Comment: Hi Zachary, what version of MS Word are you seeing this title option?  You can now disregard my question.  But for those of you that ran into what I ran into, the key is you have to expand the file / save as window to see the title option circled above!

Comment: @kbr That is Microsoft Word 2013 on windows. Yes, you must "Save-As" to see this dialog.

Answer (score 14):

Whatever was on that link, I did it opening the PDF with a hex editor (HxD) and searching `Title`, so I found `/Title (untitled)` somewhere and just edited it (changed the value between parentheses, here `untitled`).

Comment: Great answer! You can change it in vim as well. Just do "vim <your_file_name.your_file_extension" and search for title by typing "/Title" and then edit it.

Comment: The best (and only valid) answer in my opinion! In the same place where you find the title of the document, you can also edit or add other metadata, such as `/Author`. Regarding `/Title`, make sure you are editing the right one, because this attribute can also be used to name entries in the table of contents. The format is pretty intuitive.

Comment: However, it is wiser to use tools like pdftk, as described [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27381/how-to-edit-pdf-metadata-from-command-line), rather than editing the PDF file by hand. Otherwise you rapidly end up with a corrupted file that some applications refuse to open (believing it has wrong DRM, or whatever).

Comment: I don't have "title" in my pdf at all.

Comment: Not useful anymore. Acrobat PDF reader says that the file is damaged and cannot be opened after changing.

Answer (score 8):

no need to change in meta of pdf. just to following change in iframe url 
http://localhost:8080/getDataPDF//?patientId=145. use // to solve this problem it can hide your title.

Answer (score 5):

#### Open the PDF document in Adobe Acrobat Pro: (OR use google chrome extension)

- (1) Go to **Select File > Properties**
- (2) Select the Description tab to view the metadata in the document, including the document information dictionary
- (3) Modify the **Title field** to add or change the document's Title entry

Comment: - When you open pdf in chrome you can hit print and save as pdf.
- As file name write what you want as a title in the browser, it should be the same now.

Comment: If you are using fillable forms, this method will delete the fillable form feature and you will not be able to type in the fields.

Comment: You have copied your answer from https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/PDF18.html. Do not present the work of others as your own.

Comment: @redshift Agree

Answer (score 3):

When you open pdf in chrome you can hit print and save as pdf. As file name write what you want as title in browser, it should be the same now.

Comment: Dont' do this if you have fillable forms -- it will delete the fillable form capability.

Comment: This is misleading, because OP wants to change the metadata field Title, not the file name.

Answer (score 3):

Open `File > Properties`, then in the box labeled 'Title', add your title.
Click on the 'Initial View' tab, where it says `Show:`, make sure the drop down says 'Document Title' instead of 'File Name'.  This works for Chrome, but sadly not IE yet.

Comment: "Initial View" doesn't exist in the Mac version of Reader. Is there any way to set this flag some other way?

Answer (score 2):

For change my pdf tittle I just open it on nano terminal, or with another text editor that open the raw, and I edit the Title field.

Comment: Worked for me. I used Notepad++.

Answer (score 2):

The title can be changed inside MS Office or LibreOffice if you have access to the source by going to **file/properties/description**.

Comment: my client present me this problem, and this was the correct awnser later to search for so mucho forums, thanks so much @Prakash

Answer (score 1):

As [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44489165/2838361) suggested, *printing* as a PDF works here if you have the source document. What the other answer perhaps got wrong was that there is an option to add a title in the print dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how, why, or when this works, but if you put `</Some words` at the end of a PDF URL, they show in the tab name (in Chrome 111, at least)

E.g. compare https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.10555.pdf%3C/Electra and https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.10555.pdf

Doesn't work for all PDFs, I doubt it works for all browsers, but thought I'd share.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [this online pdf editor](https://www.sejda.com/edit-pdf-metadata) to change metadata of a pdf file.

Answer (score -1):

The title does not come from the pdf. it comes from the word file you export it from.
Right click on the word file, go to details. change the title and export again

Good luck