# Set page title when echoing base64 string

Tags: php, pdf, base64, opencart, page-title

I have a base64 string for pdf which I need to display to the user without saving it.

I am using this code to display the pdf:

```
public function myFunction() {
  //rest of the code
  $data = base64_decode($base64_str);
  header('Content-Description: Shipment Label');
  header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
  echo $data;
}
```

It works fine, although I am not sure if this is the right way. I need help setting the page title. Currently, it is 'index.php'.

I am doing this in opencart v2.3.0.2 so i tried :

```
$this->document->setTitle('Shipment Label');
```

But it isn't working.

Comment: I think it based upon the last part of the url, you would need to use rewrite and just ignore it in your application.

Comment: I am not quite sure how to do it. My url is website.dev/admin/index.php?route=modulename/shipment/label&token=tokenstring

Comment: Make a rewrite to `http://website.dev/admin/pdf/Shipment+Label` and it will show as `Shipment Label`

Comment: I really doubt I could do that in Opencart. Isn't there any way to set it by code?

Comment: It seems that the best way to do this is in the PDF itself:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22136043/change-pdf-title-in-browser-window

Comment: I am receiving the base64 string in a response of an api call @PaulFeakins

Comment: In that case you might need to decode it, then use some string manipulation to insert the meta title tag in to the document itself.

Comment: I searched but didn't find anything. Do you have any link or something to  guide me ? @PaulFeakins

Comment: Well I was thinking you could find how PDFs are encoded and how meta title is embeded and then you could do that but a very quick search doesn't turn up much.

Comment: Yeah I tried but couldn't figure out.. Thanks though :) @PaulFeakins