# Change title of object pdf

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am getting pdf from API as a stream of data. I'm converting it into a blob and opening it in the Object tag. The PDF is opening but the title is like `a2e08787-0376-430b-b7c8-3581b8dd3900`. Can I change it anyhow or make it disappear? I know I can disable toolbar but that will disable other features like page navigation and printing.

```css
<ion-row class="fullScreen">
  <ion-col>
    <object class="fullScreen" id="pdfframe" [data]="pdfSrc" type="application/pdf"></object>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

```html
downloadPDF(id) {

    this._service.downloadFileWithRx(id).subscribe(doc => {
      if (doc.type == 'application/pdf') {
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(doc);
        console.log(url);
        this.pdfSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
      }

    },
      error => console.log(error)
    )

  }
```

[image]

Comment: could you check https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-set-the-chromes-pdfs-view-title/294360

Comment: Also did you try name attribute of object? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22136043/change-pdf-title-in-browser-window I think it'll be helpful for you.

Comment: Another one you may want to check is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53548182/can-i-set-the-filename-of-a-pdf-object-displayed-in-chrome

Comment: @SebaCherian I have already tried. Not working.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd I don't want to manually update the title. I can either change title while uploading the PDF or after downloading it while opening it in Object tag.

Comment: @CyrilHanquez I'm very new in web devmnt. So don't know much about service worker and its uses.