# Is it possible to bulk change pdf title in wordpress or in cpanel instead of adobe reader?

Tags: wordpress, pdf

I have pdf files in my wordpress website. https://example.com/wp-content/upload../file.pdf. When I open this in my browser the title on the tab is T:/something/something/.... I search about it and the solutions I found are associated with changing the title in adobe reader. I have hundreds of pdf file and i cannot do that for each and reupload it in the site.

Is there a way to bulk change it from WordPress. Or any code to change or hide the title? The URL is triggered with I click the download now button in the website. After clicking on download button it opens the url in the browser, is there a way to make it download without openning it in browser?

There are lots of pdf and buttons in the website. I am looking for some solution that would not require change of each file and link.

I tried search for it and found ways to changed it using adobe acrobat. Looking for something that i can do in code or bulk. even hide is a reasonable option for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change PDF title in browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22136043/change-pdf-title-in-browser-window)

Comment: @csabinho Yes and no. It only shows adobe way and resaving the PDFs is an astronomical amount of work, so doing this any other way would be a great saving of time and resources. if it’s not possible to change the title at all may be create a ‘fake' or empty title just to hide current one.